# I am trying to install a site that a larger organization sent me, where do I start?

Tags: uninstallation

I have the zip file with everything in it, but there's just not a simple way to "run"? What all do I need? Do I need my own server or should they have their own?

Comment: You should probably ask that larger organization.

Comment: As phrased, I don't think this is a specific enough WordPress question.

Comment: Double-click on `WordPress.exe`. :)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no 'run'. Assuming your zip file includes a WordPress install and a database, then you'll need access to a web server and a MySQL installation. If you just want to run it on your own machine, you could install WAMP (if on Windows) or MAMP (for Macs) - these would give you all you need to get going. If you want to make this website live, however, you need a hosting company.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress